# Why my contact form is working on localhost but not working when uploaded to web host?

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, contact-form

My contact form is working absolutely fine on localhost, but when I am uploading the code to the web(I am using Bluehost as my host) my code is not working. This is a part of my code in server.js:

```
const { text } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

require('dotenv').config(); //{path: 'custom/path/.env'}
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;

//Middleware 
app.use(express.static('public_html'));
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public_html/ContactUs.html')
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public_html/index.html')
})
```

```html
app.post('/', (req, res)=> {
    console.log(req.body)

    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'gmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'abc@yahoo.com',
            pass: '1234'
        }
    })
    
    const mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.email,
        to: 'abc@yahoo.com',
        subject: `Message from: ${req.body.firstname} ${req.body.lastname}`,
        text: `Name: ${req.body.firstname} ${req.body.lastname}\nEmail: ${req.body.email}\nPhone: ${req.body.phone}\n\nMessage: ${req.body.message}`
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) =>{
        if(error){
            console.log("error")
            res.send('error')
        } else {
            if (req.body.email === "" || req.body.firstname === "" || req.body.message === "") {
                console.log("Email, name, and message field is required!")
                res.send('Email, name, and message field is required!')
            } else if (validateEmail(req.body.email) == false){
                console.log("Enter a valid email")
                res.send('Enter a valid email')
            } else {
                console.log('Email sent:' + info.response)
                res.send('success')
            }
        }
    })
})

app.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`)
})

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

here is my ContactUs.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.3/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-eMNCOe7tC1doHpGoWe/6oMVemdAVTMs2xqW4mwXrXsW0L84Iytr2wi5v2QjrP/xp" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cn7l7gDp0eyniUwwAZgrzD06kc/tftFf19TOAs2zVinnD/C7E91j9yyk5//jjpt/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- contact form -->
    <div class="contact-section">
        <div class="contact-wrapper">
            <div class="contact-title">Send us a Message</div>
            <form class="contact-form">
                <div class="dbl-inputs">
                  <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter your first name">
                    <i class='fas fa-user'></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter your last name">
                    <i class='fas fa-user'></i>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="dbl-inputs">
                  <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone">
                    <i class='fas fa-phone-alt'></i>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    <i class='fas fa-envelope'></i>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="message">
                  <textarea placeholder="Write your message" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                  <i class="fas fa-comment-alt"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="button-area">
                  <button type="submit">Send Message</button>
                  <span>Sending your message...</span>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what is going wrong. Let me know if you need more code to figure out the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you check the port? is it the same as your expected?

Comment: For localhost I am using 9000 port and online I am writing this: const PORT = process.env.PORT || 9000;    I googled that which port number should I set up if I am uploading it on a web host and this came up. I am not sure if this is right or not.@AlanYu

Answer (score 0):

If it works on your local server, it must be due to a difference in the live server. Check your `ContactUs.html` file. If this page calls your `localhost` server, it will not work on the live server. Make sure the live version of your `ContactUs.html` is calling/submitting to the live server address and not still calling `localhost`.

EDIT:
Thank you for adding the contact page code. On this line you define your form tag:

```
<form class="contact-form">
```

If no action attribute is set (e.g. `<form class="contact-form" action="http://myserver.com/mypage">`), it will submit the form to the current page. If both your local server and contact page are running on //localhost/ then this will work. On the live page, make sure your server and contact page are running on same address and port.

If this does not work, post the error that happens when you try to submit the form.

Comment: My ContactUs.html doesn't call my localhost OR live server. @Xuan

Comment: How is your contact form submitted to the server? You might want to add the contact form/code to the question.

Comment: Just made the edit.@Xuan

Comment: I added to my answer

Comment: I believe that server and contact page are running on the same port. Regarding error, there is no error shown on the console. On the live server, my code is executing if statement(shown in server.js): if(error){
            console.log("error")
            res.send('error') rather than else statement. On the localhost, my else statement is been executed. @Xuan

Comment: I not sure how it is working on localhost. Your app.get checks for requests to '/' the root path and sends replies with 2 different pages. Normally you'd check for '/' and return the index page, and use a different app.get with a path like '/contact' to for the contact page. Also, your app.post line is waiting for post a request, but your contact form does not specify the post method, so it should be sending a get request by default (which shouldn't work). You could try adding the post method to your form tag: `<form class="contact-form" method="post">`

Comment: It is still not working after adding method="post". I took help of this youtube video to make contact form https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30VeUWxZjS8 and in this video he is not using method attribute. Let me know if you need anything else to figure out the problem!! Thanks in advance! @Xuan

Comment: You need to test if your server is receiving the contact form submission. For example, you could add a line after `app.post('/', (req, res)=> {` that prints to the console, something like this: `console.log('send button was pressed!')` and see if your server console prints the message after you press the "send message" button.